# How do I store api response data (non-persistent) in MVVM?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, model, rx-swift

I am trying to store an API response data which will be used by other network request, in my case, an access token to be included in the header for any subsequent API call. I **do not** need it to be stored persistently (which deemed UserDefaults, Keychain, CoreData etc. **not necessary**) because a new one will be provided upon logging in.

How do I store the token so that it can be accessed by other ViewModels and passed it in as an argument when making a service call? Please correct me if I got my understanding wrong.

**Model**

```
// Response data object
struct Login: Codable {
    let accessToken: String
    let type: String
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
// Call login service upon button tap
let loginOutput = loginTapped
    .filter { username, password in
        username.count >= 4 && password.count >= 4
    }
    .flatMapLatest { username, password in
        PostLoginService.build(User(username: username,
                                    password: password))
            .materialize()
    }
    .share()

let loginSuccess = loginOutput
    .elements() // Return Observable<Login>
```

**ViewController**

```
// Subscribe to response output
viewModel.output.loginSuccess
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] response in
        // Question:
        // Call a method in ViewModel to store the response?
        // How do I store this response object?
        // Store in Model's Login struct?
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one more service (`CredentialsService` for example) and store your token in this service in `BehaviorRelay`. `CredentialsService` might be a singleton and will be injected in any view model as a dependency. So, as a result, any view model will have an ability to receive a token from a special `CredentialsService`.

Comment: Is it a common practice to create a class to cache data? I understand that creating a class to store the token is necessary since a method to refresh token might be needed, other than just a get set method. For cases like an account details, the class would probably only contain a get and set method.

Comment: I don't know whether it's a common practice or not. But it looks very similar to SOA.